# Build input file cannot be found: '/TMStoreTMStore.app/TMStoreTMStore'

Tags: ios, objective-c, objective-c++

**Build input file cannot be found: '/Users/macmini/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/TMStore-gkqrvfintkszhpfqfrmttgwmrkny/Build/Products/Debug-iphoneos/TMStoreTMStore.app/TMStoreTMStore'**

Whenever add or remove arm64 and VALID_ARCHS from Excluded architecture still get the same error..

[Here is the Detail Error Description](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Xi6zE.jpg)

Comment: It seems that the binary is not generated, please share more information from the log because that message doesn't give any clue

Comment: I have provided the detail description of error log

Comment: Well the binary is not being generated but I can't see why, you should look into the log the steps before where the app is compiled and linked